# Execute script in js file on MongoDB server and view output in shell

Tags: mongodb

I have a script that I can run on the mongo command line as follows :

> load("test/my.js")

The script executes successfully and returns a true.
However, I would like to see the output of the script in the mongo shell.
Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printjson ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For output please use printjson.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured it out..

In my script I need to assign the query to a variable and print it.

For example:
I need to have this inside my script.
var c = db.messages.aggregate(
    .........
    ]);

printjson(c);

Now if I run it as I was before, I get the output on the screen;